# Show that $f(A ∩ B) ⊆ f(A) ∩ f(B)$, can the relation be improved to equality?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

I have the following question:

> Let $A,B$ be two subsets of a set $X$, and let $f : X → Y$ be a function. Show that $f(A ∩ B) ⊆ f(A) ∩ f(B)$. Is it true that the $⊆$ relation can be improved to $=$?

While I know that in these type of questions I should start by going back to the formal definition of everything stated and work from there I am having trouble stating these formally.

Usually a function can be written as ${\displaystyle \{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}}$ but how do I alter this to show that $x \subseteq A ∩ B$

Does the following work: ${\displaystyle \{(x,f(x)):x\in (A ∩ B) \subseteq X\}}$

In case it does, here is attempt:

${\displaystyle \{(x,f(x)):x\in (A ∩ B) \subseteq X\}}$

is equivalent to: ${\displaystyle \{(x,f(x)):x\in A \subseteq X \wedge x\in B \subseteq X\}}$

which in turn is equivalent to:  ${\displaystyle \{(x,f(x)):x\in A  \subseteq X\}} \wedge  {\displaystyle \{(x,f(x)):x\in B  \subseteq X\}}$

which is equivalent to $f(A) ∩ f(B)$

The biggest flaw in my work is that I am working as if I am showing equality, can someone guide me or give hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $f(S \cap T) \subseteq f(S) \cap f(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231145/prove-fs-cap-t-subseteq-fs-cap-ft)

Comment: @devianceee this was helpful but my question addressed the notion of equality as well which is why I will keep it as someone already answered)

Comment: If you have any question also similar to this on preimages and images, you can refer to [this giant list here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages). Although, I'd recommend that you try solving the questions to the fullest first.

Comment: @devianceee thanks a lot, this is very helpful.

Comment: The relation can be improved to equality if $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of proving the containment is addressed by @devianceee's comment. Listed here (plz give his/her comment upvote if this was useful to you: [Prove $f(S \cap T) \subseteq f(S) \cap f(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231145/prove-fs-cap-t-subseteq-fs-cap-ft) )

The second half of the question asks about improving the containment to an equality.

I don't believe the containment can be improved to an equality.

Consider $f(x) = x^2$  On the set $A = \lbrace -1, 2 \rbrace$ and $B=\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$

We have that $A \cap B = \lbrace 2 \rbrace$

So $f(A \cap B) = \lbrace 4 \rbrace$

Now $f(A) = \lbrace 1,4 \rbrace$ and similarly $f(B) = \lbrace 1,4 \rbrace$

so $f(A) \cap f(B) =\lbrace 1,4 \rbrace$

Clearly $\lbrace 1,4 \rbrace \ne \lbrace 4 \rbrace$ so we do NOT have that

$ f(A) \cap f(B) = f(A \cap B)$

In general.

### Interesting questions to ask:

What conditions on $f$ and the sets $A,B$ need to be added so that equality again becomes possible? How can we play around with those conditions. This can lead to an interesting rabbit hole I believe.

Comment: I think equality would be in the case of the function being one to one, or $A=B$ or $A U B=\emptyset$ , am I right?

Comment: one more question if I may ask is how I defined the set correct?

Comment: Yes its reasonable to consider a function as a set of pairs. Formally speaking all functions are relations. And all relations are just sets of pairs, so a function naturally is a set of pairs as well.

Comment: thank you @forgeyedpeas

Comment: Indeed, the problem with the $x^2$ map is that it is not injective.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang but regardless if it is injective wouldn't equality hold if  $=$ or $=∅$